# `angular-ui` "track by" not working properly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm using `angular-ui` to make a multi-select drop-down.
when I use "track by $index" when I type in search input, the item that I search for will be copied for example if I want to search for "south korea" it will be copied with any keypress and when I use "track by data.id" and it shows this error: "Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed" and it won't search properly.
my code is [here](https://thimbleprojects.org/mssoheil/498921)

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because every time the search is inputted, it request the jsondata

Maybe it's a problem here

```
refresh="getData($select.search)"
```

Comment: I put it there so I could maybe use spinner. thank you very much it solved my problem